# Removing duplicate rows and changing related foreign keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, duplication

I have found all duplicate rows and now want to delete them after I update related foreign keys in other tables so they point to the correct row.

How do I get a list of foreign keys related to my table?

I have seen a number of old posts with heavy queries and wonder if there is an easier way nowadays?

Update: I have added an answer with a working query and would be happy if there is something more simple.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200811072134.44750.andreak@officenet.no

```
SELECT
  confrelid :: REGCLASS,
  af.attname AS fcol,
  conrelid :: REGCLASS,
  a.attname  AS col
FROM pg_attribute af, pg_attribute a,
  (SELECT
     conrelid,
     confrelid,
     conkey [i]  AS conkey,
     confkey [i] AS confkey
   FROM (SELECT
           conrelid,
           confrelid,
           conkey,
           confkey,
           generate_series(1, array_upper(conkey, 1)) AS i
         FROM pg_constraint
         WHERE contype = 'f') ss) ss2
WHERE af.attnum = confkey 
  AND af.attrelid = confrelid 
  AND a.attnum = conkey 
  AND a.attrelid = conrelid
  AND confrelid :: REGCLASS = 'my_table' :: REGCLASS 
  AND af.attname = 'my_referenced_column';
```

It produces

```
   confrelid   |         fcol         |   conrelid    |     col
---------------+----------------------+---------------+----------------
   my_table    | my_referenced_column | another_table | some_column
```

Update: RhodiumToad on freenode #postgres channel gave a simpler query which however needs some parsing and filtering if only specific column is needed.

```
SELECT
  conrelid :: REGCLASS,
  conname,
  pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE confrelid = 'my_table' :: REGCLASS;
```

producing

```
  conrelid  |       conname        |         pg_get_constraintdef
------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 some_table | some_constraint_name | FOREIGN KEY (some_column) REFERENCES my_table(my_referenced_column) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: The beginning of the query and an explanation are missing.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the query, but I am not sure if I can explain it.

Comment: I just hope there is something more simple. This one is from 2008.

Comment: Well, the second one is simpler, true - however, the first one is a better fit for scripting or further (non-human) processing.  It cannot get much simpler in this case, I'm afraid.  (Also, I don't see why complexity is a problem here.)

Comment: No, not a problem, but if there is something nicer in 2015, I would like to know it :)